# Two if statements are always linked even if it's not true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two separate if else statements. Even if I think only one is true, the other always gets called and vice versa. Here it is

The first one

```
if (pension < 0 ) {
    alert("Pension value error. Try again.");
}

else if (pension > income) {
    alert("RRSP Contribution cannot exceed the income.");
}
```

The second one

```
if (unionDues < 0 ) {
    alert("Union dues value error. Try again.");
}

else if (unionDues > (income - pension)) {
    alert("Union dues cannot exceed the income less the RRSP contribution");
}
```

The if(pension > income) and if(unionDues > (income - pension)) always call each other.

the variable income is prompted before hand and the checks after are to check if the values are valid.

If my income is 100, and my pension is 50 and my unionDues is 60, i think it should only call the second if else statement but it calls both.

If my income is 1, and my pension is 2, and my unionDues is 0, both alerts are alerted as well. Does anyone know what my issue is?

Edit: Fix was simple,  i just parseFloat() everything and it worked.

Comment: Are `pension` and `income` and `unionDues` numbers?  Or are they strings?

Comment: +1 to that, beat me to it. Was just about to suggest `parseInt`ing them

Comment: Are all of these simple variables, or are some of them functions? You might want to console.log() or otherwise double check that their values are what you think they are.

Comment: They are simply variables. Also they're numbers, ints so far but it might be read as a string...

Comment: It doesn't make sense that they are both called, as there is an else in the statement, or am I completely confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should make sure that all three of your values are numbers, not strings because string comparisons do not work properly for numbers that have a different number of digits.  You want everything here to be an actual number.  If these come from users typing data, then you will have to convert them to numbers using something like `parseInt(nnn, 10)`.

---

Then, once they are all numbers, your logic has some problems.

If `pension` is greater than `income`, then both `else if` statements will be true.

The first `else if` is obvious since it's a direct `else if (pension > income)` and if pension is positive, then it will not match the first `if`.

The second `else if (unionDues > (income - pension))` will match because `income - pension` will be negative which means any position value for `unionDues` will match this condition.

---

If you only want one alert to ever be triggered, then you can put all four conditions into the same logic statement either using one `if` and three `else if` or some other form of comparison that only ever selects one condition.

Another possible solution is to accumulate the error strings and, if the error string is non-empty at the end, then show one alert with all the error conditions in it.

---

Perhaps all you need is this to only show the first error encoutered (if all your values are true numbers):

```
if (pension < 0 ) {
    alert("Pension value error. Try again.");
} else if (pension > income) {
    alert("RRSP Contribution cannot exceed the income.");
} else if (unionDues < 0 ) {
    alert("Union dues value error. Try again.");
} else if (unionDues > (income - pension)) {
    alert("Union dues cannot exceed the income less the RRSP contribution");
}
```

Comment: Can you think of an if else statement where it would only be specific for what I want to achieve?

Comment: @user2140629 - it isn't clear to me exactly what logic you're trying to implement.  I've added some options to my answer.

Comment: RRSP contribution exceeds the income. 
Union dues exceed the income less the RRSP contribution. These are the validation requirements. RRSP = pension. That is what should not happen

Comment: @user - do the parts I've added to my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes a little. Im just trying to think of one if statement that can fit it all

Comment: @user2140629 - I added the simplest multiple `else if` example to my answer.

Comment: @user2140629 - Why would you want it all in one if statement?  It's difficult to read and debug.  It's much, much better to keep the tests separate.

Comment: @jfriend00 so weird...i added those statements together and it works for the Union Dues, but if my income is 100 and RRSP is 50, i get an alert saying RRSP cannot exceed income..

Comment: @jfriend00 even weirder, i tried income = 2, pension = 1 and it worked...and other values but income = 100 and pension = 50 gives me the alert..

Comment: you must be running different code and not noticing the difference

Comment: @jfriend00 ok fixed it..i just parseFloat() everything and it fixed

Comment: given the amount of information that this post has, what you are saying makes little sense

Comment: @user2140629 - changing everything to `parseFloat()` makes no sense given what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pension < 0) {
    alert("Pension value error. Try again.");
}
else if (unionDues < 0) {
    alert("Union dues value error. Try again.");
}
else if (pension > income) {
    alert("RRSP Contribution cannot exceed the income.");
}
else if (unionDues > (income - pension)) {
    alert("Union dues cannot exceed the income less the RRSP contribution");
}
```